# button要素のonclick属性に仕掛けた関数が未定義となり起動できない

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

標題の件、問題の関数inicheck();はHEADタグ内で記述するjs/entry.jsの中にfunctionとして記述しています。 画面を開いてonclick属性を仕掛けたボタンを押下しても、無反応となってしまいます。
ブラウザの開発ツールを開くと、案の定　定義されていませんというエラーになっていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問：

onclick属性で定義した関数を、外部ファイルに書くことはできないのでしょうか？inicheckという関数を動作させるための対策をご教示ください。

```
-HTML-
 

   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>申請画面</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/entry_style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/entry.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="get" action="">
            <div  class="ctrl">
            <button type="button" class="iabtn" onClick="inicheck();">確認</button>

    以下HTML省略



-js/entry.js-

$(function() {

    //テキストボックスへフォーカスあてる。
    $("input[type=text]").eq(1).focus();

    //カレンダ表示。
    $("#calendar").datepicker({minDate: "0d", maxDate: "+30d"});

    //日付枠は入力できないようにする。
    $("#calendar").keydown(function(event){
        return false;
    });


    //　省略


    //****【これが作用しない】****
    function inicheck () {
        alert("今夜が山田");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inicheckという関数がグローバルスコープに定義されていないからです。
jQueryを使っているならjQueryのイベントハンドラを使用した方が
自然だと思いますが、何を理解できていないのか理解するために修正するなら

```
$(function() {
    //テキストボックスへフォーカスあてる。
    $("input[type=text]").eq(1).focus();
    //　省略
});

function inicheck () {
    alert("今夜が山田");
}
```

という感じで関数をjQueryのハンドラの外に定義してみてください。

Comment: urin 様　早速のご回答ありがとうございます、外に出したら無事動作できました。JQueryのイベントハンドラを使用した方が．．．について調べてみます。ほんとに何も分かっていなくて

Comment: お蔭様で$(".iabtn").on("click", function() {
  alert("今夜が山田");
}); で出来ました。click()との違いがよく分かっていませんが、調べてみます。